# powershell execute math on array elements

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to perform math on two arrays but i'm always ending up executing on the arrays itself and not it elements. how do i call each element from both arrays and perform math on them one by one?

```
$array1 = (1,2,3)
$array2 = (1,2,3)
$do | % {$array1 + $array2}
```

this adds the arrays together as in:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

but the result i am looking for is the following:

```
2
4
6
```

how do i have to go about this?

Comment: `0..($array1.length-1)|%{$array1[$_]+$array2[$_]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `for` like this:

```
$array1 = (1,2,3)
$array2 = (1,2,3)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array1.Length; $i++){
  $array1[$i] + $array2[$i]
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
6
```